# Purge local user form Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

Couldn't find exactly what I was looking for in the forum...

I was testing AD Sync with a virtual domain controller. I have since deleted the virtual domain controller and need to remove the users from Azure AD. How is that done? "Delete Users" is not allowable when the user is from a local AD. Also, how do I turn off AD Sync in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Delete Users" is not allowable when the user is from a local AD

For the on-premise synced objects, you could not manage or remove from the Azure AD.

If you want to remove the synced users and turn off the AD Sync, you could follow this way:

1. Install the [Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj151815(v=azure.100)#install-the-azure-ad-module).
2. [Connect to Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj151815(v=azure.100)#connect-to-azure-ad) by using Windows PowerShell.
3. Disable directory synchronization. To do this, type the cmdlet `Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled –EnableDirSync $false`, and then press Enter.
4. Check that directory synchronization was fully disabled by using the Windows PowerShell. To do this, run the cmdlet periodically:`(Get-MSOLCompanyInformation).DirectorySynchronizationEnabled`.
   This cmdlet will return True or False. Continue to run this cmdlet periodically until it returns False, and then go to the next step.
5. Try to update an object by using Windows PowerShell or by using the cloud service portal. By this step, you could remove the synced users.

For the details, you could read [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2619062/you-can-t-manage-or-remove-objects-that-were-synchronized-through-the).

Comment: Thanks for the directory sync solve. That worked great!

Answer (score 0):

My question was in two parts.

1) Disable directory sync. This is answered by @SunnySun-MSFT above.

2) Remove local AD users from Azure AD. For this MSFT support got back to me with a working solution.

- Open powershell as admin
- Install-msolservice (provide global admin credentials)
- Get-msoluser -all -synchronized (display all local users synched with Azure)
- Get-msoluser -all -synchronized | remove-msoluser -force (delete synched users)